# htaccess - obtain IP Address from file

Tags: .htaccess

I have PHP script which collects the current DHCP address of a certain domain which is written to a file.

I need to read the IP address from that file (or collect it directly from within the `.htaccess` file) into a section of my `.htaccess` to allow only that certain IP address to be able to login to my account.

I used to use:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/wp-login\.php$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ blackhole.html [L,R]
```

I am now hosted on a LiteSpeed server which does not do reverse DNS lookups so I am unable to use any hostname lookups.

An easy solution required please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/wp-login\.php$
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ blackhole.html [L,R]
> ```

*Aside:* This code would effectively *block* that specific user, not "allow" them. You would have needed to *negate* the first condition. ie. `!^example\.com$`

However, whether the server is configured to perform hostname lookups isn't necessarily a problem of LiteSpeed itself. It's probably just how the server is configured. Many shared hosts disable this feature for performance reasons.

---

Unfortunately though, your problem is still LiteSpeed with regards to reading a value from an external file in `.htaccess`.

You can do something like the following using an Apache expression on Apache 2.4+ to read an IP address from an external file and compare it to the `REMOTE_ADDR` server variable:

```
RewriteCond expr "file('%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/ip-address.txt') != %{REMOTE_ADDR}"
RewriteRule ^wp-login\.php$ /blackhole.html [R,L]
```

Where `ip-address.txt` is a file in the document root that contains only an IP address (and no newlines).

HOWEVER, on LiteSpeed this simply does not work unfortunately. It just fails silently (the LiteSpeed way).

---

*Aside:*

Although, instead of *redirecting* to `blackhole.html` it would be preferable to just serve a 404 or 403 Forbidden. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^wp-login\.php$ - [R=404]
```

Comment: Thank-you for your reply.

The contents with or without the correct ip address in ip-address.txt does not appear to be read as it lets me login either way. (The file contains only one line containing one ip address....Have tried without/with a CR after the address). ip-address.txt resides in the public_html folder.

This coding does not work on  my Apache 2.4.43 .htaccess either. What Apache module is required for the RewriteCond expr call?